# Player getting stuck when hitting a wall pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I tried to make an enemy turn around when hitting the wall and it's getting stuck.

This is the code for just the enemy: (The size of the screen is 1000 by 1000 btw)

```
xEnemy = random.randint(0,1000)
yEnemy = random.randint(0,1000)

#enemy
def enemy():
    global xEnemy, yEnemy
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(xEnemy,yEnemy,15,15))
    
    if xEnemy > 0 and xEnemy < 1000:
        xEnemy -=velEnemy
        if xEnemy < 0 and xEnemy > 10:
            xEnemy += velEnemy
```

Comment: `xEnemy < 0 and xEnemy > 10` is never true.  Also, even if you adjusted it to what you probably mean, beware (a) the effect of nesting this `if` underneath the previous one, and (b) the possibility of triggering both conditionals, so you subtract `velEnemy` and then add it again, for no resultant effect.

Comment: `xEnemy < 0 and xEnemy > 10` should be replaced with `xEnemy < 0 or xEnemy > 1000`. Also, if this condition is true you want to reverse the velocity of the enemy afterwards, `velEnemy = -velEnemy`

Comment: if xEnemy > 0:
        xEnemy -=velEnemy
    if xEnemy < 1000:
        xEnemy += velEnemy

Comment: This code makes the makes to enemy stand cuz both conditions are true at the same time

Comment: So how do I make him switch directions when he reaches the end

Comment: You need to fix your indentation and change one of your conditions because the enemy will freeze when xEnemy == 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the velocity if `xEnemy > 1000` or `xEnemy < 0`. If `xEnemy > 1000`, the velocity has to become negative. If `xEnemy < 0`, the velocity has to become positive. The absolute amount of the velocity can be get with `abs(velEnemy)`. Don't forget `global velEnemy`

```py
def enemy():
    global xEnemy, yEnemy, velEnemy

    if xEnemy < 0:
        velEnemy = abs(velEnemy)
    if xEnemy > 1000:
        velEnemy = -abs(velEnemy)
    xEnemy += velEnemy

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (xEnemy, yEnemy, 15, 15))
```